# Explain $(\|Mx\|_2)^2 = (M^Tx)^T(M^Tx) $ (positive definite, positive semi definite)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Would really appreciate if someone can explain:

$$
(\|Mx\|_2)^2 = (M^Tx)^T(M^Tx)
$$

can't get my head round with this.

Comment: What's the connection between $A$ and $M$?

Comment: A is just M, was a typo, my apology

Comment: Perhaps that first $M$ should be $M^T$?  $(\|Mx\|_2)^2 = (M^T x)^T (M^T x)$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $u,v$ are column vectors of the same size,
$$
\langle u,v \rangle = u_1v_1 + \cdots + u_n v_n = v^Tu = u^Tv
$$
Note, then, that
$$
\|u\|^2 = \langle u,u \rangle = u^Tu
$$
now, set $u = Mx$.